# Is it possible to select the parent of the parent with SCSS

Tags: sass

I have a SCSS file with the following

```
input{
  &[type="text"],
  &[type="search"]{   
    margin: 0 0.5em;
    }
  }
```

which works as expected. I would also like a textarea to have the same CSS. Does SCSS have a selector that will allow me to place textarea with the

```
&[type="text"], &[type="search"]
```

in the SCSS file but not place the 'input' parent before textarea. The output I'm trying to achieve is as follows

```
input[type="text"], input[type="search"], textarea {
    margin: 0 0.5em;
}
```

I know I could do this with a mixin however I was thought this feature was added to SCSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@extend works really great in these situations. % is good as a way of implying that this class will only ever be extended.

```
%baseClass{
    margin: 0 0.5em;
}


input{
    &[type="text"],
    &[type="search"]{   
        @extend %baseClass;
    }
}

textarea{
    @extend %baseClass;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot.  For a lengthy selector, The best you can do is set it as a variable and use that.

```
$form-input-text: unquote('input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="search"], input[type="email"], input[type="tel"], input[type="url"]');

#{$form-input-text} {
    // styles;
}

#{$form-input-text}, textarea {
    // styles
}
```